# Can't seem to compare to varchar in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, triggers, compare, varchar

I'm trying to make sure that when people create tables it starts with the prefix `tbl`

Here is what I did as of now:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
    DECLARE @name VARCHAR(25)

    SET @name = (SELECT TOP 1 name 
                 FROM sys.tables 
                 ORDER BY create_date DESC)

    IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@name, 1, 3) != 'tbl'
       PRINT 'Tables must begin with the prefix tbl'

    ROLLBACK
GO
```

The problem is it doesn't let me use `!=` operator. I tried using `=` `<>` or `LIKE` but nothing seems to work it keeps telling me that the syntax is incorrect please help I looked everywhere online and everybody says that `=` or `LIKE` work. :(

Comment: Well if you are dumb like me and don't know how to dix your problem remember to close you SELECT like so (SELECT SUBSTRING(@name,1,3))!= 'tbl' Then everything will be fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error is because of a missing closing bracket at:

```
IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@name,1,3) != 'tbl'
```

can be fixed by adding the missing closing bracket:

```
IF (SELECT SUBSTRING(@name,1,3)) != 'tbl'
```

However, you don't need to do a select to perform substring.

You can do this:

```
IF SUBSTRING(@name,1,3) != 'tbl'
```

Comment: Thx guys now that it has been answered do I need to close it or check a answered box.??? New to this site

Comment: @TristanClaude set this answer as accepted one, as this screenshoot <http://i.imgur.com/EwgMSN2.png>

Comment: Thank you very much Hadi

Answer (score 3):

Though the other answer explain the issue in your code. I will suggest you to use [**`Eventdata()`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms173781.aspx) function to retrieve table name

Also your `DDL` trigger will `rollback` every `Create Table` action even though the table name starts with `tb1`. You need to apply `rollback` only when table name not starts with `tb1` move the rollback command inside the `IF` condition.

Use `BEGIN-END` block when `IF` condition has more than one statement else the first statement alone will considered inside the `IF` condition.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_tbl
ON DATABASE
FOR CREATE_TABLE
AS
  BEGIN
      SET NOCOUNT ON

      DECLARE @TABLE_NAME SYSNAME

      SELECT @TABLE_NAME = Eventdata().value('(/EVENT_INSTANCE/ObjectName)[1]', 'SYSNAME')

      IF LEFT (@TABLE_NAME, 3) != 'tbl'
        BEGIN
            PRINT 'Tables must begin with the prefix tbl'

            ROLLBACK
        END
  END

GO
```